# android app has unfortunately stopped

Tags: android

I am trying to run this app on android emulator but it shows "Unfortunately the app has stopped working":

```
package com.example.myapp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    static int counter;
    static Button badd, bsub;
    static TextView text;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        counter=0;
        badd=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
        bsub=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
        text=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        badd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                counter++;
                text.setText("your total is :"+counter);
            }
        });


        bsub.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                counter--;
                text.setText("your total is :"+counter);



            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

xml code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="start"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="your total is 0"
        android:textSize="65sp"

         />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="100sp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="add"
           />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="100sp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="117dp"
        android:text="subtract" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Log cat shows the following:

```
caused by java.lang.nullpointexception
```

Answer (score 1):

Add **android:id="@+id/button2"** in your second **Button**.

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="100sp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="117dp"
    android:text="subtract" />
```

Problem was not giving any "id not defined" error is following line of code in **second button** view.

```
android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button2"
```

Though you have declared it with "@+id" it will create a new id. And will not give any error in your Activity code. Change that code with what i have written above.

Comment: thanks guys it is working after adding id for second button.Thanks

Comment: @user2429908, glad to help you but accept and up vote answer so that other googler guys can get benefit of it. :)

Answer (score 0):

For the second button add

```
android:id="@+id/button2"
```

and change

```
android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/button1"
```

to

```
android:layout_alignLeft="@id/button1"
```

Change your layout as follow:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="start"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="your total is 0"
        android:textSize="65sp"

         />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="100sp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="add"
           />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="100sp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/button1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="117dp"
        android:text="subtract" />

</RelativeLayout>
```